What explanations can be offered for the extreme see-sawing in Montana's senate race polling?
Glancing at Five Thirty Eight data for Montana's senate race between Testor and Sheehy, the pattern that emerges is summarized (in order of polls closing earlier):

Sheehy, narrow margin (+2, Emerson College);
6 days later - Sheehy, large margin (+6, APR - Change of 4 points for Sheehy);
2 days later - Testor, large margin (+5, RMG - Change of 11 points for Testor);
6 days later - Sheehy, large margin (+7, POS - Change of 12 points for Sheehy).

That's a lot of change packed into a two-week period.  Is polling in Montana especially volatile, are there campaign events meaningfully yanking the needle around back and forth, what's the story there?

We're talking about changes of a few percentage points here. I can't help but feel this is just the standard level of variance you get with polling. The graph charting Trump and Harris' polling figures looks smooth, but you can see similar variance if you look at the individual polls.

You should put the actual figures and pollsters in the question. But since they're all from different pollsters, probably with different methodologies, it's not surprising. You need to look at the results from the same pollster over time.

@StuartF I guess I'm just shocked that even with different methods, pollsters could be 10+ points away from each other within the same period.

Are you really just asking for a collection of theories that would be consistent with those observations?

@WilliamWalkerIII Asking the same question in different ways can generate a larger spread than 10 points.

The majority of people don't pay any attention to local races until right before the election. Thus, their opinions are highly variable.

Doesn't the margin of error in polls go anywhere from 3-7% or higher?

@WilliamWalkerIII If you think that's bad, looking at this A rated poll right before the election: https://www.usnews.com/news/elections/articles/2020-10-28/biden-opens-gaping-17-point-lead-on-trump-in-wisconsin-poll-finds - Polls should never be trusted.

You should take into account that the polls were commissioned by different organizations, that the actual questions asked are not reported, nor are the confidence levels given. A +2 lead with a confidence interval of 3 points is completely compatible with a +6 lead with the same interval.

Pollster Quality
A major premise of 538 is that all polls are not equally informative. Different polling organizations use different methodologies, and that creates biases within the polls.
So just looking at the 538 Pollster Ratings, you can see that the Emerson College poll is solid - Emerson is ranked 8 out of all the pollsters 538 has graded, with 2.9 stars out of a possible 3.
In contrast, Public Opinion Strategies is significantly lower quality - ranked 139 with 1.7 out of 3.0 stars.
RMG is ranked 60, with 2.3 / 3.0 stars, and I couldn't find APR, though there's a Polling and Research Inc, which is ranked 68, so close to RMG if that's APR under a different name.
Putting all that together with just vibes and no math, I'd say that we throw out the POS poll, weight ourselves towards the high quality Emerson poll, and say "in August it was too close call with perhaps a slight lean R."

In addition Emerson and POS measure likely voters compared to RMG and APRP measuring registered voters, which are two different competitions.

Polls funded by Republican organizations tend to be biased toward Republican candidates, while polls funded by Democratic organizations tend to be biased toward Democratic candidates. If one ignores those biased polls, what the remaining polls do show is margin of error. I would not call those 5 to 6 point swings for or against one candidate or the other volatile.
There is a basic problem with modern polling, which is that many people simply don't answer (do you pick up a phone call from an unknown number? I don't), or if they do answer, many give a smart *ss reply and hang up. How polling organizations deal with this basic problem varies with different polling organizations. This adds to the margin of error.

Also worth considering is the possibility of a correlation between political leaning and willingness to answer a poll.

@WGroleau: That is not only worth considering--it's something reputable polling organizations have done for decades when trying to estimate what fraction of the total population would answer in each way.  This race is sufficiently unique in many ways, however, that estimates of such effects based on historical trends are likely to be unreliable.  Many people who have historically voted Republican have indicated that they're "never-Trumpers", but it's unclear how many people would identify themselves to polsters as Republicans or Democrats.

I was thinking more along the lines that certain personality traits might cause one to lean a certain way politically and make him/her consider a poll an unwanted intrusion.

Margin of Error
When you take their margins of error into account, what every one of these polls show is that the candidates are in a virtual dead heat.
This was actually one of the reasons that 538 originally started combining multiple polls into weighted aggregates: to increase the overall reliability.  The fact that even 538 seems to no longer be doing their aggregates for Senate races, and is now even burying the margin of error/quality information 3 to 5 clicks deep is sad indeed.

Indeed. With N=1000 people, the margin of error will be around +/- 3 percentage points, while with N=500 people, it's about +/- 5 points. Some of the individual poll-to-poll changes may appear "significant" (like 44% to 51%), but that's only when you retrospectively cherry pick the ones with the highest differences to test. By and large, support numbers aren't changing at meaningful levels. There's an issue of multiple hypothesis testing here as well, if you compare enough polls you'll eventually find some with seeming differences by chance alone.

Sampling bias is more likely to produce the results in the OP than statistical uncertainty.

Perhaps the 3 people in Montana still willing to answer polling calls have decided to mess with the polling organizations?
